# JDBC limitation on lists

Tags: python, jdbc, teradata, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to write a data migration script moving data from one database to another (Teradata to snowflake) using JDBC cursors.

The table I am working on has about 170 million records and I am running into the issue where when I execute the batch insert a maximum number of expressions in a list exceeded, expected at most 16,384, got 170,000,000.

I was wondering if there was any way around this or if there was a better way to batch migrate records without exporting the records to a file and moving it to s3 to be consumed by the snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

If your table has 170M records, then using JDBC INSERT to Snowflake is not feasible.   It would perform millions of separate insert commands to the database, each requiring a round-trip to the cloud service, which would require hundreds of hours.

Your most efficient strategy would be to export from Teradata into multiple delimited files -- say with 1 - 10 million rows each.  You can then either use the Amazon's client API to move the files to S3 using parallelism, or use Snowflake's own PUT command to upload the files to Snowflake's staging area for your target table.  Either way, you can then load the files very rapidly using Snowflake's COPY command once they are in your S3 bucket or Snowflake's staging area.

Comment: Another approach you can try, if you are using cursors to read data, is to loop over data in batches of 16,000 rows at a time (below the list record limit) and construct a single INSERT command per batch.  Snowflake supports the syntax `INSERT INTO <table> values (a,b,c), (d,e,f), ... (x,y,z)` where every tuple represents a different row.  That would dramatically reduce round-trips, but still likely be slower than loading from multiple files in S3.